# Download file to specific directory via Selenium (IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea

I am using Selenium to click on the element and download the file. But IntelliJ IDEA automatically created a subdirectory with a random name for the directory specified by me as a place for storing downloaded files. Because of that I cannot use the path of my directory for the next tests.
Does somebody know how to avoid the automatic creation of subcategories while downloading files?

Comment: Selenium downloading files to an Intellij-created, randomly named directory sounds like a behaviour caused by specifics of your project configuration. I think we may be missing some information. Would you share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.